# Audio in my App, play pause slider

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

Guys I'm getting errors with incorporating the UISlider into my audio app, any advice would be great, this is my first app and I'm a newbie...

The track plays fine, stops fine but when I try and skip the app crashes out, I'm sure I've missed something out, just need some fresh eyes on the code, hope someone can advise...

**NoGraceViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface NoGraceViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    UISlider *volumeControl;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UISlider *volumeControl;
@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *skipSlider;

-(IBAction) nograceButton;

-(IBAction)playbutton;

-(IBAction)stopbutton;

-(IBAction)skipSliderMoved;

@end
```

**NoGraceViewController.m**

```
#import "NoGraceViewController.h"

@interface NoGraceViewController ()

@end

@implementation NoGraceViewController
@synthesize skipSlider;
@synthesize timeLabel;

-(IBAction) nograceButton { 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/no-grace-original-mix-single/id392597812?uo=4"]];
}

@synthesize audioPlayer;

- (IBAction)playbutton
{
    [audioPlayer play];

}

-(IBAction)stopbutton
{
    [audioPlayer stop];
}

- (IBAction)skipSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.audioPlayer.currentTime = self.audioPlayer.duration*sender.value;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"001.mp3" ofType:nil]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", 
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setSkipSlider:nil];
    [self setTimeLabel:nil];

    self.volumeControl=nil;
    self.audioPlayer=nil;
}

-(void)updateDisplay { 
    self.skipSlider.value = self.audioPlayer.currentTime / self.audioPlayer.duration; 
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)   self.audioPlayer.currentTime / 60,(int) self.audioPlayer.currentTime % 60];
    self.timeLabel.text = timeString;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.audioPlayer.currentTime = (self.audioPlayer.duration / 100) * sender.value;
```